# Running android APK on mobile data pack

Tags: android

I developed an android application and installed the apk in the device. It worked fine when it was connected to a contralized wifi router. However the application stopped working when i switched my android device to mobile data pack. Should I provide some extra permission apart from **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`** in the manifest file??

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: Please post the code that fails according to logcat.

Comment: Increase the connection timeout period for your network operations

Answer (score 0):

to perform the network operations described in this lesson, your application manifest must include the following permissions:

```
  < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This code snippet tests network connectivity for mobile. It determines whether these network interfaces are available (that is, whether network connectivity is possible) and/or connected (that is, whether network connectivity exists and if it is possible to establish sockets and pass data):

```
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
...      
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```